# LIBGDX how to add sprite from a texture atlas

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to know how I can add a sprite from a texture atlas so I can implement it as a sprite for my main menu.

Here is my code for the main menu:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    CrazyZombies game;
    Stage stage;
    TextureAtlas atlas;
    Skin skin;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    TextureRegion firstLayer;
    TextureRegion secondLayer;
    TextureRegion thirdLayer;
    TextureRegion fourthLayer;
    TextureRegion fifthLayer;
    TextureRegion sixthLayer;
    TextureRegion seventhLayer;
    TextureRegion eighthLayer;
    TextureRegion ninthLayer;
    TextureRegion tenthLayer;
    TextureRegion eleventhLayer;

    public MainMenu(CrazyZombies game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.09f, 0.28f, 0.2f, 1);

        batch.begin();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        skin = new Skin();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
        atlas.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }

    public void loadLayers() {
        TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/mainmenu/MainMenu.pack"));
        firstLayer = atlas.findRegion("1layer");
    }
}
```

So I need to go about getting firstLayer onto the screen and every way I have tried ended with a crash.

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing it right. Your render method doesn't have any draw. Take a look at the [SuperJumper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper) demo in libgdx.

To answer on how to create a sprite-

```
Sprite mySprite;
...
...
mySprite = new Sprite(someTextureRegion);
        mySprite.setSize(SOME_WIDTH, SOME_HEIGHT);
        mySprite.setOrigin(SOME_WIDTH/2f, SOME_HEIGHT/2f);
        mySprite.setPosition(world.sprite.bounds.x, world.sprite.bounds.y);
...
...
mySprite.draw(batch);
```